# Getting only the delimiters using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following String which I would like to split and get only the delimiters!

For example:

```
-3/*1         --> [/*]
3/1           --> [/]
22/*23/off    --> [/*,/]
-bar/12(2)/14 --> [/,/]
14/*4(3)      --> [/*]
1/*7/*11      --> [/*,/*]
```

I have this regex template:

```
"\\w|[(]|[)]|[-]"
```

but it doesn't work well, it does remove the unnecessary numbers and brackets, but it gives extra empty cells in the output array.

Any idea how to improve it?

Thank you!

**EDIT1**

I found that splitting with this expression also works

```
"[^/\\*?]"
```

but again - it leaves empty cell in output array.

Answer (score 3):

Do matching instead of splitting.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("/\\*?").matcher(s);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while(m.find()) {
  list.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: I tried:   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("/\\*?").matcher(""-3/*1");    int c = m.groupCount();    and c=0 ?!?

Comment: ya, there isn't any capturing groups used.

Comment: It's working - checkout the answer below this one - I'm trying to see if I can make it work in JAVA.

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex: `(\/\*|\/)`:

Usage in JS:

```
"1/*7/*11".match(/(\/\*|\/)/g) => ["/*", "/*"]
```

Comment: /g means recursive, it allows to get all matches not only the first

Comment: global match (not recursive)... In [tag:java] would be the same as **looping** `matcher.find()`, instead of just calling it once

Comment: I've tried this in JAVA:     "1/*7/*11".match(/(\\/\\*|\\/));    but didn't get the same results as in JS, any idea why?